# How to add named variables to class init (or any function)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this class signature (the **init** signature):

```
class TensorDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, *tensors)
```

this class is initialized in this line:

```
dataset = TensorDataset(all_input_ids, all_attention_mask, all_token_type_ids, all_labels)
```

now I would like to wrap the this class, so I created CustomDataset:

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, *tensors, **keywords):
        self.tensor_dataset = TensorDataset(*tensors)
        self.all_text = keywords["all_text"]
```

and I also tried:

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, *tensors, all_text=None):
        self.tensor_dataset = TensorDataset(*tensors)
        self.all_text = all_text
```

But when I try to initialize this class like this:

```
dataset = CustomDataset(all_input_ids, all_attention_mask, all_token_type_ids, all_labels, all_text: all_text)
```

I get an error:
End of statement expected
Statement expected, found Py:RPAR

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying with all_text: all text, but named args should go like

```
all_text=all_text
```

so try that.